# Macro: Edit Recorded MobaXterm Macro

Tags: hadoop, ssh, terminal, macros, xserver

How can recorded `MobaXterm Macro` can be edited so that it can take input from the user and append it to a query and then executing rest of the macro after?

Answer (score 5):

There is a macro tab in the left toolbar where you can edit your macros, see:
https://superuser.com/a/1588231/319387

It's a bit weird that this is the only way to access them for editing, deleting etc.

Answer (score 3):

You may create 2 different types of macro:

1. **Session start-macro**:

   - edit or open a new ssh session
   - Advanced SSH settings -> Execute Macro at session start: ->
   - new window appears to edit macro steps ...
   - insert new line ... etc.
   - save with OK-Button when finished.
2. **Macro recording with Menu Entry Macro**:

   - open Macros Menu (right beside Help)
   - select record new macro
   - "do what You need to do"
   - select stop
   - chose Macro Name and press OK

New macro appears in ***Macros Menu***.

Regards,
Sascha.

Answer (score 1):

[Click on the Macros tab present in the left side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J5Du.png)

It shows the list of macros created.
Right click on the macro which you want to edit. Choose the appropriate option and
Rename/Edit/Delete/Duplicate/Execute ..etc.